# List of other hosts in ansible, without the current host

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have these hosts in my `hosts.yml` file:

```yaml
all:
  hosts:
    host1:
      name: name1
      port: port1
    host2:
      name: name2
      port: port2
    host3:
      name: name3
      port: port3
```

I want a string with all of my hosts in the `hosts.yml` file with ports like:

```
"http://name2:port2, http://name3:port3"
```

Without the current host (in my example, `http://name1:port1`).

I want this to be generated for each host when the ansible-playbook is run, and I want to pass it to my app in the startup process like (for host1):

```
$entrypoint.sh otherUrls="http://name2:port2, http://name3:port3"
```

I use this code to make the string:

```yaml
  otherUrls: "{%- for host in groups['all'] -%}
    {%- if hostvars[host]['name'] is defined -%}
      {%- if name != hostvars[host]['name'] -%}http://{{ hostvars[host]['name'] }}:{{ hostvars[host]['port'] }}
        {%- if not loop.last -%}\", \"{% endif -%}
      {% endif -%}
    {% endif -%}
  {% endfor -%}"
```

I made this with jinja2. But I still have an extra `','` at the end of the string for the last host. Are there any ideas to get rid of the problem?

Comment: You need to provide an example of what you have done so far. See [how much effort is expected from SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/9401096)

Comment: I edited it, is it clear now? @Zeitounator

Comment: This is still a requirement, not a question. You are not demonstrating what you have already tried and what is the exact programming problem/error you are facing. SO is a place to ask and answer questions about programming problems., not a market place where you ask developers to write code for you (see my above link). Chances are you will have to show a bit more effort to attempt to implement your requirement yourself if you want better chances to get an answer.

Comment: Also, I added my code to generate the string. Is it clear now?

Comment: It's much better and can be answered. But now you have to wait for the question to be reopened to accept answers. Since my solution is a oneliner, I'll provide it here and provide a full answer later if possible. `other_urls: "{{ groups['all'] | reject('==', inventory_hostname) | map('extract', hostvars) | json_query('[][name, port]') | map('join', ':') | map('regex_replace', '^(.*)$', 'https://\\g<1>') | join(', ') }}"`

Comment: Please make sure to provide a full [mre] from start in your next question to avoid being in the same situation again.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to my problem without json_query:

```
    {%- set groups_without_this = [] -%}
    {% for host in groups['all'] -%}
      {% if node_name != hostvars[host]['name'] -%}
        {% do groups_without_this.append(host) -%}
      {% endif -%}
    {% endfor -%}
    {%- for host in groups_without_this -%}
      {%- if hostvars[host]['nname'] is defined -%}
        {%- if name != hostvars[host]['name'] -%}http://{{ hostvars[host]['name'] }}:{{ hostvars[host]['port'] }}
          {%- if not loop.last -%}\", \"{% endif -%}
        {% endif -%}
      {% endif -%}
    {% endfor -%}
```

This code creates a new list without the current node and then constructs the "otherUrls" string.